# Pandas : How to remove only the last hyphen at the end of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have test dataframe below

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A-08', 'ABC-11-05', 'B-A-CC', 'C', 'D'],
    })


    id
0   A-08
1   ABC-11-05
2   B-A-CC
3   C
4   D
```

I tried using this below code to remove only the last **hyphen** but it's not working..

```
df['id'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('-$', '', x) but it returned the same thing.
```

I would like to have desire result as

```
    result
0   A
1   ABC-11
2   B-A
3   C
4   D
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

split at the end, with just a count of one, then keep only the first index

```
df['id'].str.rsplit('-', 1).str[0]

0         A
1    ABC-11
2       B-A
3         C
4         D
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a lambda function and a combination of join + split to achieve that:

```
df.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x['id'].split('-')[:-1]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `-[^-]*$`:

```
df['id'].str.replace('-[^-]*$', '')

0         A
1    ABC-11
2       B-A
3         C
4         D
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Where `-` matches the hyphen, `[^-]*` matches **non** hyphen sequence, `$` matches end of string. Overall the regex matches a pattern that starts with `-` and followed by non hyphen characters until end of string.